# UK visitor visa from Lahore Pakistan

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistan

This a procedural question but very confusing , kindlh help if anyone knows
People who are applying for UK visitor visa from Lahore Paksitan are they going to scan the documents
And also take the documents packet

and what about dependents do they have to provide photocopy set of each and every document of the main applicant ?

Answer (score 2):

The document scanning facility is provided by VFSGlobal without any extra charges. You can upload your documents at home or you can use the document scanning facility at Gerry's Lahore. No need to make extra copies as it is clearly mentioned on Documents checklist that they don't need **multiple copies of similar documents**. If all members of the family are using same bank statement then just carry one copy with you (no need to get extra for every person) because your documents will be scanned and returned back to you. They will just submit your printd application along with documents checklist and passport. Rest of the documents will be returned back to you after scanning. **Make sure to take printout of document separators with you from vfsglobal website, otherwise you will have to pay 1700 Rs just for those 9 pages** Hope you are satisfied:)

**Edit: From now onward you have to select Appointment from VFSGlobal website instead of within the application. Also, you need to pay 13.39 pounds for document scanning assistance and you may have to pay extra depending upon available slots (eg premium lounge slots, prime time appointment etc)**

Comment: Thanks for your update, that will help many people.

Answer (score 0):

The documents are being scanned and uploaded on UK visas and immigration sites. Then they want to return the documents back to applicants.
We were 1 independent applicant and 2 dependent applicants. No need of photocopy sets for applicants. The documents of dependent like their own identity card or any property will be uploaded on their own application.
Other than this all the documents will be uploaded on the main applicant. There will ne no repetition in the documents scanned and uploaded. 
Because of system slow down the Office kept the copy of documents submitted so that if there is any issue in the uploading of documents they have a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

From today onwards 10 May 2019 they are also taking a charge of PKR 2600 for scanning document of each applicant.